# Instantiate List<I> dynamically

Tags: c#

All -

I am trying to dynamically (at runtime) want to create a people collection which has 3 attributes - Name, Skillset and Collection of addresses.

the problem I am facing is I cant add the address in the following line at the time of instantiate.

```
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "John Smith", Skillset = "Developer", _________ });
```

So essentially how do i combine these 3 lines into 1 so I can pass it above:

```
Person per = new Person();
per.Complete_Add = new List<Address>();
per.Complete_Add.Add(new Address("a", "b"));
```

Here is my full program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PersonViewModel personViewModel = new PersonViewModel();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Skillset { get; set; }
    public List<Address> _address;
    public List<Address> Complete_Add
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set { _address = value; }
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public string OfficeAddress { get; set; }

    public Address(string _homeadd, string _officeadd)
    {
        HomeAddress = _homeadd;
        OfficeAddress = _officeadd;
    }

}

public class PersonViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        people = new List<Person>();
        Person per = new Person();                   \\Dont want to do this
        per.Complete_Add = new List<Address>();      \\Dont want to do this
        per.Complete_Add.Add(new Address("a", "b")); \\Dont want to do this
        people.Add(new Person() { Name = "John Smith", Skillset = "Developer", Complete_Add = per.Complete_Add });
        people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Mary Jane", Skillset = "Manager" });
        people.Add(new Person() { Name = null, Skillset = null });
    }

    public List<Person> people
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still do it through Property Initialisers

```
 people.Add(new Person() { Name = "John Smith", Skillset = "Developer", 
      Complete_Add = new List<Address>
      {
           new Address("a", "b")
       }});
```

Comment: Thanks everybody - the property initialisers works - its the {} brackets which I was missing. Really appreciate the help here

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's what constructors are for. Create a constructor for `Person`, and initialize the properties as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work:

```
Person per = new Person() { Complete_Add = new List<Address>() { new Address("a", "b") } };
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can also have your property instantiate the list if it is not already

```
private List<Address> _address;
public List<Address> Complete_Add
{
    get { return _address = _address ?? new List<Address>(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do your initialization in the [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx):

```
public class Person
{
   public Person() 
   {
      this._address = new List<Address>();
      this.Complete_Add = new List<Address>();
   }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Skillset { get; set; }
    public List<Address> _address;
    public List<Address> Complete_Add
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set { _address = value; }
    }
}
```